# Ensure variable is view not copy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two large dataframes, with the same layout, that I want to reference based on some state. I don't want the assignment to create copies as that would be slow and a memory hog.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
switch = True
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
if switch:
    df_used = df1
else:
    df_used = df2
# now use dataframe but don't change it ...
return df_used['A'][0]
```

I want to make sure that df_used is a view not a copy. I'm just not sure how to ensure that. I know how to avoid the slicing issue but this is the reverse, I want to ensure i'm on the view.

Comment: `df_used` is **neither a view nor a copy**, it *is* one of the two dataframes. Assignment **never copies or creates a new object**

Comment: Ah yes, i'm still back in the old days of writing assembler. Old habits die hard sometimes :) Thanks